Oh My Zsh + iterm2 - Wrong characters showing
I'm using the iterm2 with omz - version "master (130002a)".
From the last update versions, it's started to show strange characters. I've already tried to set different fonts, etc., and also related topics, but nothing has solved the problem.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it?


I've found the fix :)
The issue was on the theme I was using.
I changed to the official theme, and now it's working fine.
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
